# filter by values that appear in one or another column in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have this data frame:

```
intA <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'L')
intB <- c('B', 'D', 'T', 'T', 'B', 'K', 'M')
num <- c(1:7)
num2 <- c(6,6,7,7,7,6,7)
df <- data.frame(intA, intB, num, num2)
df
```

and I want to filter the data frame when in column intA or intB appears value A or T, I know how to filter by one or another, but I need to filter boths at the same time:

```
library(dplyr)
p <- c('A', 'T')

filter(df, intA %in% p)
filter(df, intB %in% p)
```

the expect output would be:
intA intB num num2
1    A    B   1    6
2    A    D   2    6
3    A    T   3    7
2    D    T   4    7

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both conditions with OR, i.e., the | operator.

```
filter(df, intA %in% p | intB %in% p)

  intA intB num num2
1    A    B   1    6
2    A    D   2    6
3    A    T   3    7
4    D    T   4    7
```

´´´

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(grepl('[AT]', intA) | grepl('[AT]', intB))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  intA  intB    num  num2
  <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A     B         1     6
2 A     D         2     6
3 A     T         3     7
4 D     T         4     7
>
```